# Slider thumb not being changed when slider value is changed if the user is holding the slider's thumb

Tags: wpf, slider, mouse

I have a custom user control called ImageTemplate. This control contains an image and has functionality that allows the user to do stuff to the image displaying. When a particular event fires, the image will switch and the settings for the ImageTemplate (displaying the new image) will be reset to default.

One functionality of the ImageTemplate is to allow the user to zoom in and out and when the image is changed, the zoom level has to be set back to default (100%).

There are three ways the user can zoom:

1. Hold down the control button and use the mouse scroll wheel to zoom in and out
2. Select a zoom level between 20% and 200% using a ComboBox
3. Select a zoom level using a slider control

I am having problems with the slider control.

For the ImageTemplate, I have implemented a dependency property called Zoom and I handle this property's DependencyPropertyChangedEvent so that I can call the logic that performs the zoom scaling.

The slider control's value is bound to the Zoom property like so:

```
<Slider x:Name="sldZoom"
        Minimum="{Binding MinZoom, Source={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
        Maximum="2" 
        TickFrequency="0.2"
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
        SmallChange=".2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200">
        <Slider.Value>
            <Binding Mode="TwoWay" Path="Zoom"
                      RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"
                      UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                      ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"
                      ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
        </Binding>
    </Slider.Value>
</Slider>
```

Now when the user drags the slider, the control zooms to the appropriate level.
Also, the slider changes to the correct position when the user zooms using the mouse scroll button or the ComboBox.

The problem occurs when I am dragging the thumb of the slider control and the image changes.

I want the thumb to move back to the "100%" position because that its the default zoom of images; however it does not move to that position.

How do I get around this problem?

Thank you,

-Frinny

Comment: Try to set `sldZoom.Value = 100` on the `ValueChanged` event. That worked for me. (Note that i'm not using Databinding)